# How can I work with the objects returned by 'tabs.query()'?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-addon, web-extension

I have three tabs open, when I print `activeTab`, on the console I get:

```
let activeTab = browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true})

...
0: Object { id: 1, index: 0, windowId: 1, … }
1: Object { id: 2, index: 1, windowId: 1, … }
2: Object { id: 3, index: 2, windowId: 1, … }
length: 3
...
```

If I try to work with the object, such as getting its length or try array indexing into it, I just get `undefined`:

```
activeTab.length // undefined
activeTab[1]    //undefined
```

I am trying to familiarise myself with this method and its return object, such as getting the `tabId` property. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: [browser.tabs.query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query) is asynchronous and returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you need to use async/await or `.then`

Comment: The duplicate is regarding Firefox and the use of `then()`, but the solution is the same for your case too

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan will go through that question. Thank you!

Comment: @BenFortune This promise thing is really hellbent on skewering me. How does one know if an object is a promise or a just a standard array/object? I suppose I will find out soon enough. I will read up on them some more, thank you for the pointer.

Comment: The documentation for `browser` says that. Most of the methods are asynchronous.